# Why do so many methods use Collection rather than Iterable?

Tags: java, iterable

With C# I grew to love the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. There are a lot of cases where that's all you want to give out and take in. In addition it's useful in the .Net library. You have for example a constructor on the `List<T>` class which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.

I have to work with Java at the moment, and I naturally wanted to use the equivalent `Iterable<T>` interface. However, it doesn't really seem like I can use it anywhere. Everything seems to be using the extended `Collection<T>` interface instead. Why is this?

As an example, you have the `ArrayList<T>` constructor which takes a `Collection<T>`:

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Why not just take an `Iterable<T>` instead?

Comment: If I read the docs right, `Iterable` does inherit from `Collection` and you should therefor be able to send it in whenever a `Collection` is required. I might be mistaken on that, though.

Comment: @Bobby, If so I wouldn't have asked this :P Unfortunately it's the other way around.

Comment: @Bobby it's the other way around Collection inherits Iterable.

Comment: @bestsss: Oohhh...I've just started out with Java, so please pardon my ignorance. The term `subinterface` sounded like it would inherit from that interface, not the other way round...reading the docs again I now realize that `Iterable` is declared as `superinterface`...doh...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterable was only added in Java 5.  This means older methods (most of them) use collections.  Even newer methods which could take Iterable haven't used it. :(

I think the problem is that most Iterable are Collections.

Comment: And maybe because developers are not aware of the interface, or just "lazily" use the Collection interface, like they used to.

Comment: I think the problem is that Iterable has only one method which is not very useful. Most of the time List and Set are used as these are interface which have all the method you might need.  However when developing libraries (like Collections) I agree it is best to use the most specific interface you need.

Comment: Since Collection inherit from Iterable, wouldn't it be possible to just swap them out though?

Comment: @Svish, not without breaking existing compiled libraries, or having to double up all the method calls.

Comment: Ok, but I guess it could be fixed in a new version of Java then? Since you'd have to recompile to use it? As far as I see, code shouldn't need to be changed, it would just have to be recompiled?

Comment: Backward compatibility is often the claim used when they don't want to change anything.  You can take a library compiled for Java 1.0 and run it in Java 7.  To what extent anybody does this, and whether there is another way to fix this. e.g. have some sort of auto-migration of the binary, is another question. IMHO, doubling up the methods isn't such a bad thing and it can be largely hidden (by placing the double methods at the end of the class (and having some way of neatly folding them in the javadoc)

Comment: IMHO, The biggest backward compatibility issue is 32-bit sizes for collections. I have written articles on what would need to be done to use 64-bit sizes for collections and how backward compatibility might work. Today you can buy a 1 TB server for $70K and this price is falling all the time. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey sorry to disagree 3 times in one day but backward binary compatibility is essential in any programming language. It is its own justification, it doesn't need another explanation. I encountered one case in 1995 where it hadn't been maintained and the screams were audible across the ocean. That's the last time I've seen it.

Comment: @EJP, I agree that backward compatibility is essential, however it doesn't mean there is no way we can fix it and not retain backward compatibility. To me that appears to be the implication. Perhaps it is harder and some work arounds very ugly, but it doesn't mean it can't be done. IMHO.  Perhaps people have had enough bad experiences attempting to do this, to not want to try again. BTW You can disagree with me as often as you like. I learn more that way. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey (a) you cannot change a method signature without breaking binary compatibility, (b) if it ain't broke don't fix it, and I still don't see any evidence that anything is broken.

Comment: @EJP, (a) This is true, but it doesn't mean you can't add a method which takes an Iterable, which application which where re-compiled would use and deprecate the existing methods (b) I don't think its as black and white as that but I think this is an example of where if we designed Java again we might do it differently, but isn't worth changing now.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey sure but the OP is specifically talking about *changing* the method signatures.

Comment: @EJP, I would change the method signature of the method implementing the code, and add a deprecated method which just calls that for backward compatibility (and hide it at the end of the class perhaps)  For co-variant return types, the compiler creates two methods for you and perhaps the syntax could be extended to specify this.  something like `min(Iterable<E> | Collection<E> iterable)` however, just adding a method for backward compatibility is simpler IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

> As an example, you have the ArrayList constructor which takes a Collection

Having predictable size is good, esp. for an ArrayList (it does use toArray() to build its underlying Object[])

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Lovely sun were lazy to update the docs again, it doesn't use iterator at all;
Actually myself I almost never read the docs since they often tend to be either mislead or just plain wrong.

Also you can easily fit an Iterable to a Collection by subclassing AbstractCollection (which lacks only size() and iterator() readily implemented)

Iterable was introduced mostly to conform `foreach` construct.

Comment: Of course i could, but then I might as well use Collection. My issue is that I don't want to use Collection, because Collection is Iterable and Iterable has what I need. I have gotten used to try to always use the slimmest interface I can, and it annoys me that Java forces me to not do that :p

Comment: you know what is annoying: that need for size when you impl. a proxy (Collection/Map) to JDO, since to determine the size of the (JDBC) result , you need either to read it wholly or use scrollable ResultSet. Iterable suffers from the same issue, if you need to copy the content there is no size estimation available which leads to poorer performance.

Comment: @bestss - *"it doesn't use iterator at all"* - actually, it depends on whether the collection's implementation of `toArray` uses the iterator under the hood.  Some do, others don't.  So if we are being pedantic, the javadoc is inaccurate, but if you change "are returned" to "would be returned" it is accurate.  (FWIW, all list classes that inherit their `toArray` method from `AbstractCollection` via `AbstractList` do use the iterator.)

Comment: Also, the `toArray()` specification says: *If this collection makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.* Thus, it **is** the same order as the iterator, if this order is somehow defined (and the implementation does not violate the specification).

Comment: @Stephen, the c-tor doc should not rely on under the hood details, it clearly doesn't use iterator, hence it shall state it. Back in the day there was an error since some impl. Arrays.asList (namely) didn't return Object[] but some specific type and attempting to add an arbitrary different object resulted in ArrayStoreException... Doh forgot the main point: even arrayList doesn't use iterator.

Comment: @Paŭlo, the point is of course valid and I am not arguing about the order of the elements at all; the main reason not to use iterator but toArray() is usually the implied atomic behavior of toArray() compared to multiple calls to itearator (and risk of ConccurrentModificationException). Not implementing toArray() is also a valid Collection or having significantly more expensive toArray() than iterator(). That's my main gripe: it is misleading.

Comment: If you want more functionality for working with `Iterable`s (and collections in general, take a look at [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

Because they want to allow doing more with the collection than just iterating over it?

Comment: That could make sense when returning something, but not when taking it as a parameter. When you take something in as a parameter, you should use the minimum interface you can use. If all you need is iterating over a collection, you should take in Iterable instead of Collection.

Comment: @Svish So the methods want to do more that iterate. You don't have any evidence to the contrary.

Comment: For example `ArrayList.addAll` shouldn't need `add`, `remove`, `indexOf`, `size` et cetera. `size` might be handy to optimize things, but it should rather just check if the Iterable is a Collection and use the `size` only if it is.

Comment: @Svish you're missing the point. The assertion is being made that most methods don't want to do more that iterator over a collection, so they can be passed an Iteratable instead of a Collection. I don't see any evidence for the claim. It is also *wrong* to specify Iterable if it is going to be cast to something else internally. If the method requires the API of Collection it should declare it as a Collection.

Comment: Well, if you don't see any evidence for that claim, I'll just say thank you and end the discussion here :)

Comment: @Svish the point is that you haven't *provided* any evidence. You can't. You don't know why the APIs were designed the way they were. You don't know what's in the 'everything' that 'seems to be using the extended Collection<T> interface'. Specifically, you don't know that they only iterate. When you have some facts let's continue the discussion.

Comment: When looking through the APIs I don't find much which take Iterable, most take Collection, which was the reason for me wondering. You are correct that I don't know why they were designed that way, and that's why I asked this question to begin with. I was wondering why. Because to me it doesn't make a lot of sense. Maybe because I've gotten used to the (in my opinion) much cleaner APIs of .Net. 

If you look at the source of ArrayList for example, the only method it calls on the incoming collection is `toArray`. Shouldn't be too difficult turning an Iterable into an array in my opinion.

Comment: @Svish not difficult, just impossible, because it would break binary compatibility. So it can't be changed. As for why it is how it is, Collection is @since 1.2 and Iterable is @since 1.5.